# What's the best "insert all images" plugin?

Tags: images, media, uploads, customization

I've tried several plugins that supposedly allow you to "insert all images" after using the flash based uploader to upload multiple images.

However, I still haven't found one that ties in well with the latest version of wordpress in a non-hacky way. Which plugins the most for inserting multiple images?

[image http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/4746/pictureu.png](http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/4746/pictureu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/faster-image-insert/

Answer (score 1):

Skip the Plugin. You don't need a PLugin merely to insert all images attached to a post.

Just use the `[gallery]` shortcode (also available as an "Insert Gallery" button in the Media Manager on the Edit Post screen).

**EDIT**

IF you want to display commentary for each one, here's a suggestion:

1. Use the "caption" field in the Media Manager, to add your commentary for each image
2. Pass the `size="large"` and `columns="1"` parameters to the `[gallery]` shortcode, e.g. **`[gallery size="large" columns="1"`**, to output a single column of large-sized images, each of which will output your commentary as their caption.

Comment: What if I want to add them all at once and then write content around each one?

Comment: See edit to answer.